# Creating a Python HTML code snippet with pygments/python-markdown/django-markdownx

Tags: pygments, python-markdown, django-markdownx

What is the correct way of creating a HTML code snippet with `pygments` / `python-markdown` / `django-markdownx`? Basically, I am trying to make it look like the code blocks in the official Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Example: I am trying to convert the following piece:

```py
>>> s = "Hello World!"
>>> print(s[0])
H
```

By using the back tics in Markdown (normally not indented, fix for posting here):

````
    ```python
    >>> s = "Hello World!"
    >>> print(s[0])
    H
    ```
````

The result from `python-markdown` is as follows:

```html
<div class="codehilite">
<pre>
<span></span>
<code>
<span class="o">&gt;&gt;&gt;</span> 
<span class="n">s</span> 
<span class="o">=</span> 
<span class="s2">&quot;Hello World!&quot;</span>
<span class="o">&gt;&gt;&gt;</span> 
<span class="nb">print</span>
<span class="p">(</span>
<span class="n">s</span>
<span class="p">[</span>
<span class="mi">0</span>
<span class="p">])</span>
<span class="n">H</span>
</code>
</pre>
</div>
```

Which is almost what I need. Except, I would like to have the `>>>` as `class=gp` and the result `H` as `class=go`:

```html
<span class="gp">&gt;&gt;&gt;</span>
 
<span class="go">H</span>
```

It has probably something to do with how to write the input, but I cannot figure it out how to do it. Any help is very much appreciated!